# pander markdown tables with pipes inside not processed correctly

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, pander

I generate markdown tables with pander R package that have pipes in some column titles (like : P > |t| ). It seems (unless I missed something) that they are not correctly processed neither by pandoc nor by Rmarkdown due to the confusion between column separators and "true" pipes.

Consider the following Rmd example:

````
```{r  message = FALSE}
library(pander)
panderOptions("table.style" , "rmarkdown")
panderOptions("table.split.table" , Inf) # avoid to split the tables

data(iris)
mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
```

```{r results='asis'}
pandoc.table(summary(mod)$coefficients[,-4])
```

```{r results='asis'}
pandoc.table(summary(mod)$coefficients)
```
````

The last table generated by pander looks like this (note the pipes in the last column name):

```
|                  &nbsp; |  Estimate  |  Std. Error  |  t value  |  Pr(>|t|)  |
|------------------------:|:----------:|:------------:|:---------:|:----------:|
|         **(Intercept)** |   5.006    |    0.0728    |   68.76   | 1.134e-113 |
|   **Speciesversicolor** |    0.93    |    0.103     |   9.033   |  8.77e-16  |
|    **Speciesvirginica** |   1.582    |    0.103     |   15.37   | 2.215e-32  |
```

If I knit this to html (via Rstudio button that uses Rmarkdown to generate the HTML if I'm not wrong), the last table is not displayed as a table but as plain text in the HTML output.
If I use the md generated by knitr and transform it into html with pandoc the output is a table but the last column name becomes "Pr(>".

The first table without the last column is displayed correctly.

Comment: It might be a good idea to ask around on the Pandoc mailing list or [issue tracker](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues) how to escape pipes with this table format/syntax. A possible workaround for now would be using some Unicode characters for "real pipes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape the pipes with a backslash (`\|`).

Comment: OK thank you, it works indeed.  @daroczig : do you think it would be possible for you to change pander to handle this ? I just added : ```colnames(t) <- gsub("\\|", "\\\\|", colnames(t)) ; rownames(t) <- gsub("\\|", "\\\\|", rownames(t)) ; t <- gsub("\\|", "\\\\|", t)``` in your pandoc.table.return function (after the part applying the format function) and it worked. But of course this should require more testing.

Comment: @Gilles - a [recent commit](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/commit/f9405716281499ee5946b70c1014ba0638c3b685) should auto-escape any pipes found in the table, but please verify. Any thank you (+1), John, for the quick and really useful answer!

Comment: Great thanks a lot! It works fine for pandoc. But with knit2html and Rstudio the tables are still displayed not correctly even when the pipes are escaped (I also tried with a double backslash). Maybe an issue with R markdown package ?

Comment: @Gilles - I suspect it's a `markdown` pkg issue then. Maybe it would be a good idea to ask around here: https://github.com/rstudio/markdown/issues?state=open